# compiling glib with non-standard paths

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I am trying to compile `glib-2.32.1`, therefore I installed `libffi-3.0.1` into the following path:

```
~/localroot/lib/
```

and the header files are in:

```
~/localroot/lib/libffi-3.0.11/include/
```

However, when I do configure:

```
~/tmp/build_alot/glib-2.32.1 $ ./configure --prefix=~/localroot
```

I see the following error:

```
checking whether to cache iconv descriptors... no
checking for ZLIB... yes
checking for LIBFFI... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libffi >= 3.0.0) were not met:

No package 'libffi' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBFFI_CFLAGS
and LIBFFI_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

What are the correct values that I need to set for  `LIBFFI_LIBS` and `LIBFFI_CFLAGS` in order to successfully compile glib?

#### tiny bit of extra info:

When I compiled libffi I got the following helpful info:

Libraries have been installed in:
   /home/nahum/localroot/lib

```
If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
test -z "/home/user/localroot/share/info" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/user/localroot/share/info"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../doc/libffi.info '/home/nahum/localroot/share/info'
 install-info --info-dir='/home/user/localroot/share/info' '/home/user/localroot/share/info/libffi.info'
test -z "/home/user/localroot/lib/pkgconfig" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/user/localroot/lib/pkgconfig"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libffi.pc '/home/user/localroot/lib/pkgconfig'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/tmp/build_alot/libffi-3.0.11/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/tmp/build_alot/libffi-3.0.11/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/tmp/build_alot/libffi-3.0.11/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
```

Setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/home/user/localroot/lib/pkgconfig` still does not bring success.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### on the way to enlightenment...

I managed to compile glib with:

```
export LIBFFI_CFLAGS=-I/home/user/localroot/lib/libffi-3.0.11/include
export LIBFFI_LIBS="-L/home/user/localroot/lib -lffi"
```

Now I have to see if the dependencies down the road are all happy with how I compiled it.

Comment: @L'angeCarasuelo, your welcome! I guess the people behind SO are going to sleep with a smile, knowing their servers are working for a good cause.

Comment: In my case, I used sudo ./configure LIBFFI_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include LIBFFI_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lffi"

Comment: always check ./configure --help to know available options/environment variables

Answer (score 4):

For those like me who were wondering where the `-I` and `-L` and `-lffi` flags came from (Oz123's answer), I found out that they can be found in:

```
/home/user/local-software/libffi-3.1/lib/pkgconfig/libffi.pc
```

Reading the file gives:

```
...
...
Libs: -L${toolexeclibdir} -lffi
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Use the `Libs` and `Cflags` location to set the `LIBFFI_LIBS` and `LIBFFI_CFLAGS` variable, respectively. Now if you run `./configure` then `make && make install`, things should work (at least they did for me).

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the OP's question.